# Enabling CSRF on Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, csrf-protection

There seems to be no documentation on how to enable CSRF protection using Rack::Protection in Sinatra for forms. Anyone ever done this? I can't seem to figure out how to tell Sinatra to enable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sinatra [readme](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#configuring-attack-protection) says that it's enabled by default. So there is no need to enable it.

And if you need something like `Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken` you can just add this middleware with a use in your config.ru or your main application file.

example:

```
require 'rack/protection'
use Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken
```

Comment: Yes, but.. it does not appear to do anything. I made a form which submits data and had no CSRF token it. Sinatra let it pass without a comment.

Comment: My best guess, since i can't try it right now is: you need to include `Rack::Protection::FormToken` or `Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken` yourself since it's not included with rack::protection https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection#cross-site-request-forgery (this is the part with the example in my answer)

Comment: I did this but could not see the AuthenticityToken anywhere, so I'm not sure if the protection is applied. Any way to check?

Comment: The issue is, I think, that if you do NOT add an authenticity_token, the form STILL works anyway, so the Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken appears to be doing nothing

Comment: What worked for me was in my Classic app I needed to move the session and Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken initialization code BEFORE the code that defined my routes. Once I did that, all my app forms would fail until I added the <input type=hidden name=authenticity_token value='#{env['rack.session'][:csrf]}'> (which of course was the desired outcome, eg, that the CSRF token was needed).

Answer (score 3):

The Sinatra website is unhelpful in this regard, but CSRF tokens can be enabled as described in the [comments](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/180158b725b8a964711ef8bdb3c8cbaf53d2e6a3/rack-protection/lib/rack/protection/authenticity_token.rb) above the `Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken` module.

The token is stored under `env['rack.session'][:csrf]` and will have to be manually added to your forms under a hidden input named `authenticity_token` (or whatever you configure it to use).

For example:

```
require 'rack/protection'
use Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken

get '/' do
  "<form method=post action=/hello>
     <input type=hidden name=authenticity_token value='#{env['rack.session'][:csrf]}'>
     <input type=submit>
   </form>"
end

post '/hello' do
  'hello' # will fail unless a valid authenticity_token parameter is passed
end
```

The difference between `Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken` and `Rack::Protection::FormToken` is that the latter one will not require the token if the request is made through AJAX.